# 5/3/1 Assistance work for deadlift and OHP

Tags: weightlifting

I am running 531 3 days a week, combining the OHP and the deadlift on the same day. My question is what to do for assistance work on these days? For my squat and bench I'm running boring but big, but I'm confused as to what to do on my ohp/deadlift day.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely suggest to do "carries"; such as Farmer's walk (2 or 1 hand). It is pretty good for deadlift assistance.

Chin-ups would be good for everything :)
There are lots of alternatives, they would all have some benefit. You can use BBB for OHP also; you can do high rep lateral and front raises.

For deadlifts, you can do speed deadlifts, or power cleans. It is all up to you, you can do hamstring work such as leg curl, you can do stiff-leg deadlifts.

Comment: If you want "hamstring work", then do rdls, not leg curls. http://breakingmuscle.com/strength-conditioning/the-king-of-hamstring-exercises

Comment: What about the pyramid down sets as described in beyond 531 for the deadlift, and then 3 way shoulder raises? Would that be sufficient?

Comment: I am in no place to state anything Wendler says as insufficient :).

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on where you are weakest on those lifts.  However, there are a few options that I've found very useful.

**OHP Assistance:**

- More **OHP**.  You can use dumbbells or barbells.
- **Z Press**. Sit on the floor with legs straight out and press from a rack.  Works the shoulders and core more.
- **Incline Press**.  Dumbbells or barbells here as well.  Stick to close grip for more triceps work

There are others, but these have been good staples for me.

**Deadlift Assistance:**

- **Double pause deadlifts**.  Pause just off the floor and just below the knee.  They are brutal so keep the weight down.  They drill motor patterns and build strength in the most common sticking points. 5x6-8
- **Snatch Grip Deadlifts**.  Use straps and work off of blocks (2-4").  These hit the glutes, hamstrings, and upper back well.  Even just 2-3x15 is enough.
- **Opposite stance Deadlifts**.  If you normally do conventional, do assistance with sumo style.  Or flip it if your normal style is sumo.  They hit your muscles differently enough to be good assistance for the other.  3x8-12.
- **Romanian Deadlifts**.  If you have to go mixed grip or use straps to keep the weight where it's challenging, do it.  5x10-15.

You can treat it as a menu of assistance work.  For example, if your lower back is pretty taxed before you start deadlift assistance, you might want to stick with snatch grip deadlifts or romanian deadlifts.  If you are feeling good and want a challenge go with the opposite stance or double pause variations.  Also, as assistance work, touch and go is perfectly fine.  In fact with longer rep sets, it's about the only real way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If I were deadlifting and overhead pressing as my main exercises, the first things I'd look to for assistance would be pull-ups, dips, or power cleans. The pull-ups help the upper back for OHP, the dips help the triceps and shoulders for OHP, and the power cleans train speed and explosiveness for the deadlift.